Firebase Cloud Messaging Section Stuck on Loading
I'm experiencing an issue with the Firebase Console where the Cloud Messaging section is stuck on loading. After inspecting the developer console, I found that an API call to the Identity Toolkit API is returning a 404 error.
Error Message:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}

API Endpoint Returning Error:
https://identitytoolkit.clients6.google.com/v1/brands/[Your Project ID]?alt=json&k


Verified that the required APIs (Identity Toolkit API, Firebase Authentication API, and Firebase Cloud Messaging API) are enabled in the Google Cloud Console.
Checked API key permissions to ensure they are correctly configured.
Cleared browser cache and cookies, and tried accessing the Firebase Console in incognito mode.
Tried different browsers and networks to rule out browser or network-specific issues.
Verified that service accounts have the necessary permissions.
Consulted the Firebase Status Dashboard to ensure no ongoing outages.


https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/SfaugAtHkCTsqFVN2b4f
